# How to get unique values from specific column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table

```
tblFruit_ID tblFruit_FruitType tblFruit_FruitName
--------------------------------------------------
1            Citrus              Orange
2            Citrus              Lime
3            Citrus              Lemon
4            Seed                Cherry
5            Seed                Banana
```

I can't set `distinct for tblFruit_FruitType` column only, and if I use `group by` (I want only count function), then also I am getting an error.

My expected output:

```
tblFruit_ID   tblFruit_FruitType   tblFruit_FruitName
------------------------------------------------------
   1            citrus                   orange
   4            seed                     cherry
```

Comment: You just need to 'Select Distinct tblFruit_FruitType from TableName'. I think this will fetch you what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Window Function`

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER (PARTITION BY tblFruit_FruitType ORDER BY tblFruit_ID) rn,
                *
         FROM   tablename)
SELECT tblFruit_ID,
       tblFruit_FruitType,
       tblFruit_FruitName
FROM   cte
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: Hi sir, could you explain this query.. Thanks in advance

Comment: @VickySiddharth Please don't use the word `SIR`. Check this link https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/window-functions-in-sql/

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT  t.[tblFruit_ID],t.[tblFruit_FruitType],t.[tblFruit_FruitName]
from
(SELECT [tblFruit_ID],[tblFruit_FruitType],[tblFruit_FruitName]
FROM tbl) t
 join
(SELECT min([tblFruit_ID]) [tblFruit_ID], [tblFruit_FruitType] 
FROM tbl
GROUP BY [tblFruit_FruitType]) x
ON t.[tblFruit_ID]=x.[tblFruit_ID] 
AND
 x.[tblFruit_FruitType]=t.[tblFruit_FruitType]
```

Comment: sir i should not to give like col2=citrus because its a large table am working , i put just eg., by using query i want to get that output...

Comment: fixed it.you can try it now.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Group By to get Min fruitID by fruitType and then just use available FruitIds in IN operator to get required data.

Check this:

```
Select tblFruit_ID, tblFruit_FruitType, tblFruit_FruitName
From tablename
Where tblFruit_ID in 
(Select min(tblFruit_ID) From tablename Group by tblFruit_FruitType)
```

Comment: @VickySiddharth: Yes, it would return min fruitid but for each fruittype. Hence, dont think that it will return only one record. It will return min record for each type.